# UINavigationController subclass won't set titleView on load

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I've just created a simple subclass of `UINavigationController`.

```
#import "TTNavigationController.h"

@implementation TTNavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoView;
}
```

But when I run the project the navigation bar has not the `titleView` with the logo.

Otherwise if I try to move those 3 lines of code in `viewDidLoad` of my view controller works fine. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `self.navigationItem` because the navigation controllers own `navigationItem` is never used. It has this property because it is a type of view controller but it isn't actually displayed because the `viewControllers` (or, more specifically, the `topViewController`s) `navigationItem` is displayed.

So, change the view controller `navigationItem` (either directly, or when it is pushed).

Comment: Thanks Wain. So I should create a `UIViewController` subclass, right?

Comment: You can use a navigation controller delegate, or a VC subclass. It depends if all views should have the same title and what VCs you have. Delegate is more flexible.

Comment: I like more the delegate approach. Which is the delegate's method you were thinking about for this case?

Comment: navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:, or you could subclass and override the push methods.

Comment: Oh I got it! So all I need to do is set up `navigationItem.titleView` property of the view controller in that delegate's method, thanks!

Comment: I spent a day to resolve this. Thank you so much. :) Subclassing is the best way.