# Navigation UI not updating with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uinavigationitem

I tried to update my navigationItem titleView when I finished downloading data model from server.

Something like this :

```
private func loadNews() {
    self.newsModelManager.sendRequest(inBackground: false, preSendHandler: { (isReachable) in
        if isReachable {

        } else {
            appDelegate.showInternetFailedAlertView()
        }
    }, successHandler: { (response) in
        print("loadNewsModel: successHandler")
    }, errorHandler: { (response) in
        print("loadNewsModel: errorHandler")
    }, reloginFailHandler: { (response) in
        appDelegate.showReloginFailedAlertView()
    }) { (isReachable) in
        let array = self.newsModelManager.loadFirstFiveNews()!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setupTitle_ViewWith(array: array)
        }
    }
}
```

and in seupTitle_ViewWith(array:)

```
func setupTitle_ViewWith(array: [NewsModel]?) {
    guard array != nil else { return }
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
    let newsTitle_View = NewsTitleView(newsModelArray: array!, frame: frame)
    newsTitle_View.newsTitleViewDelegate = self
    self.title_View = newsTitle_View
}
```

this all works fine, until the last line `self.title_View = newsTitle_View`

I thought this would update my titleView to my CustomView,
But it's not....
What might went wrong there?

I first save model from server with realm and read at `let array = self.newsModelManager.loadFirstFiveNews()!`

But, say if I have data in device already and read directly without loading first, it works totally fine...

Comment: Can you try to execute the setupTitle_ViewWith(array: array) without  DispatchQueue.main.async {} block

Comment: Hi, just tried. no luck

Comment: One doubt, why are you calling setupTitle_ViewWith() function on isReachable closure instead of successHandler ? I hope you should be updating the view once after success download right ? Any specific reason ?

Comment: I save dataModel into Realm on successHandler and then read data from realm on isReachable closure...

Comment: Oh, Thank you, so it seems no issue on calling function, ok then one last try could you try using "DispatchQueue.main.sync" instead of async.

Comment: I actually tried, it crashed lol, lemme see if I can get the erroe msg

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: Sorry sync will cause the exception, But for me its updating fine when I try in view controller, Are these codes inside a viewController ?

Comment: It's actually in NavigationController, does that makes a difference ?
thanks for helping btw

Comment: Yes, it does have some difference checkout this(https://stackoverflow.com/a/20923010/4510873) answer, So try to update the navigation titleView in the ViewController instead of the navigationController class itself and let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hey Bharath, it works! that makes me look dumb, can you post your comment as answer so I can accept ?

Comment: Nice to hear it solved your issue. I will post in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is the brief summary of what solved this issue for reference for others who might face the similar kind of issue,

The codes which @Ian has shared in the question has been added in the NavigationController subclass. 
The issue is caused here. Because you cannot able to update the navigation title nor the titleView from the navigation controller for little explanation refer this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/20923010/4510873)

So we tried updating the titleView from viewController and it solved our issue then.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for trying out all I asked :-) It was nice solving issues together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this by using local notifications,

1) Change your loadNews function like this,

```
private func loadNews() {
    self.newsModelManager.sendRequest(inBackground: false, preSendHandler: { (isReachable) in
        if isReachable {

        } else {
            appDelegate.showInternetFailedAlertView()
        }
    }, successHandler: { (response) in
        print("loadNewsModel: successHandler")
    }, errorHandler: { (response) in
        print("loadNewsModel: errorHandler")
    }, reloginFailHandler: { (response) in
        appDelegate.showReloginFailedAlertView()
    }) { (isReachable) in
        let array = self.newsModelManager.loadFirstFiveNews()!
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object:array)
        }
    }
}
```

2) Then in your ViewController paste this in viewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.setupTitle_ViewWith), name: "refresh", object: array)
```

3)

```
func setupTitle_ViewWith(notification: NSNotification){
    let array = notification.object as! NSArray
    guard array != nil else { return }
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
    let newsTitle_View = NewsTitleView(newsModelArray: array!, frame: frame)
    newsTitle_View.newsTitleViewDelegate = self
    self.title_View = newsTitle_View
}
```